# For lower to upper

Tags: regex

Need a RegEx to do the following:

1. Lower to upper case till the first dot (.) From left
2. Only 'S' will go upper case in s6a to S6a
3. Rest remains same.

For example:
**nhe7-s6a-mme**.epc.mnc001.mcc505.3gppnetwork.org
change to
**NHE7-S6a-MME**.epc.mnc001.mcc505.3gppnetwork.org

Comment: Does it have to be only a regex, or are you using a programming language?  This is very easy if you are using a programming language, possibly impossible if just using regex.

Comment: Only Regex is required.. I know with Programing language there are many functions to do it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really want to contribute to such a poorly phrased question, but here is a regex pattern to do this

```
match on: ([\w]+)\-(?:(\w)([\w]+))\-([\w]+)\.
substitue: \U\1\-\2\E\3\-\U\4\.

input: nhe7-s6a-mme.epc.mnc001.mcc505.3gppnetwork.org
output: NHE7-S6a-MME.epc.mnc001.mcc505.3gppnetwork.org
```

Example seen here: https://regex101.com/r/GqRcPQ/2

Comment: `\w` includes digits too.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara good point. I always forget that digits are counted as word characters.